# Disable public to download files like .env

Tags: django, nginx, plesk

How to disable download files in the root folder?

For example when I go to the link;

> https://example.com/.env

It will download the **.env** file, and

> https://example.com/projectfolder/settings.py

It will download the **settings.py** file.

How can I disable the download access?

I use Plesk Obsidian and this is my additional nginx directives in "Apache & nginx Settings" on Plesk (I only tested for .env file):

```
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_app_type wsgi;
passenger_startup_file passenger_wsgi.py;

location /.env {
     deny all;
}
```

And the **.env** is still downloadable.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you specified the nginx server the wrong way, it should only listen to requests for the media and static files.

Comment: I added the additional nginx directives in the question. Did I do something wrong? Also how to do it for all `.py` files in some folders?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out cache stores my file and need to be cleared for it not to be downloaded.

Anyway, this is what I excluded from public access for Django Project (.env, .py, .pyc, .html):

```
location = /.env {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* /.+\.py$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* /.+\.pyc$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* /.+\.html$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```